# Average Pandas Dataframe by Date

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe a list of dates

```
                       debt 
date                               
2017-11-17 16:00:00    77     
2017-11-17 17:00:00    73     
2017-11-17 18:00:00    74     
2017-11-17 19:00:00    73     
2017-11-17 20:00:00    74     
2017-11-17 21:00:00    71
```

I am trying to group by the dates to find the average by dates without time

```
2017-11-17 74
```

I tried to do this
df = df.groupby(df['date'].map(lambda x: x.day))
KeyError: 'date'

Is there any other way to do it please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If need `date`s in `index` use [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.date).mean()
print (df)
                 debt
2017-11-17  73.666667

print (df.index)
Index([2017-11-17], dtype='object')
```

But better is for `DatetimeIndex` use [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.floor('d')).mean()
print (df)
                 debt
date                 
2017-11-17  73.666667

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-11-17'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', freq=None)
```

Comment: Great thanks you are very fast, and its you again Jezrael!

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your own approach , change to `index`

```
df.groupby(df.index.map(lambda x: x.day)).mean()
Out[132]: 
           debt
date           
24    73.666667
```

Comment: Congrat to `20k` ;)

Comment: @jezrael without yours guys help , I even can not Imagine that , also, Learn a lot from you:-)